# Throttle method call as we throttle View clicks with RxJava

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-binding

Is there a way to throttle method calls i.e only take the first event within a certain window duration. I have seen examples of RxBinding like

```
RxView.clicks(mButton)
            .throttleFirst(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(...);
```

How can I do the above to a method ?

Answer (score -1):

In RxJava2 there is such operator - http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sample.html